# multi-combo box search with VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox

I am currently having this issue of my search not working correctly. The idea is to have the user click on different fields and have them assigned to textboxes and then be searched against. [image] Above is what the UI currently looks like in the form and the code is attached below. For example, when I pick firstName as the field 1  and Title as field 2, enter the text "joe" into field 1 into 
and "student" into the respective text boxes and then hit search, it shows all of the student results instead of that single row of data in the table. I am thinking this is could be an issue of the combo boxes not being synchronized, where let's say if cbo1 and cbo2 declare fields, then those repsective text fields become filtered. cboField, cboField2 and cboField3 are all combo boxes and command_21 is a search button and command_28 is a show all records. I am very new to this still and am not entirely sure. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cboField_Enter()
Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
    If Me.Form.FilterOn = True Then DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
Set oRS = Me.RecordsetClone
cboField.RowSourceType = "Value List"
cboField.RowSource = ""
    For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
    If oRS.Fields(i).Type = dbText Then cboField.AddItem oRS.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
 End Sub

Private Sub cboField2_Enter()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
    If Me.Form.FilterOn = True Then DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
cboField2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
cboField2.RowSource = ""
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    If rs.Fields(i).Type = dbText Then cboField2.AddItem rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub cboField3_Enter()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
    If Me.Form.FilterOn = True Then DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
cboField2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
cboField2.RowSource = ""
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    If rs.Fields(i).Type = dbText Then cboField2.AddItem rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub Command21_Click()
Dim sfilter As String, oRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim sfilter2 As String, rs As DAO.Recordset

If IsNull(cboField) And IsNull(cboField2) And IsNull(cboField3) Then
DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
MsgBox "select a field"
Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNull(cboField) Then
sfilter = cboField & " LIKE '" & txtBox & "*'"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , sfilter
End If

If Not IsNull(cboField2) Then
sfilter2 = cboField2 & " LIKE '" & txtBox2 & "*'"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , sfilter2
End If

If Not IsNull(cboField3) Then
sfilter3 = cboField3 & " LIKE '" & txtBox3 & "*'"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , sfilter3
End If




Set oRS = Me.RecordsetClone
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

If oRS.RecordCount And rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
MsgBox " no record matches"
DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
End If


End Sub

Private Sub Command28_Click()
DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I could not understand what is your question.

Comment: You are not combining the filters in Command21_Click -- your code, where you check if IsNull only looks at one item.  And I strongly suggest you get into the habit of making meaningful names for your controls -- it will help you and us.

Comment: combining filters? like have sfilter = cboField & " LIKE '" & txtBox & "*'" AND cboField2 & " LIKE '" & txtBox2 & "*'" AND cboField3 & " LIKE '" & txtBox3 & "*'". Wouldn't this apply all filters to one textbox and not actually match the selected field from the combo box ? Maybe I am misunderstanding

Comment: There are many, many errors in the code you shared. The first one is the one Wayne G Dunn shared (you are indeed misunderstanding), but others include (but are not limited to) not checking the combo boxes for an empty string, comparing the `RecordCount` twice on identical recordsets, not specifying the type of sFilter3. Read into creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you share less code, I can fix all errors in a concise answer.

Comment: You want to allow user to select a field from a combobox and input a parameter in a textbox? And you want to allow 3 pairs of combobox and textbox? You are loading all fields regardless of data type? Use of LIKE and wildcard is really only effective with text type fields. Have you even step debugged? Probably don't need the RecordsetClone. Set the form Filter and FilterOn properties. Use RecordsetClone along with Bookmarks to 'go to' a specific record. Instead of textboxes could use comboboxes to provide a list of valid data. More code to set the RowSource. That's my approach.

Comment: Here's good tutorial on building filter criteria with multiple controls http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html